# Attempting to compare values in two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, comparison

I have a list of users on a webpage and am trying to compare each username with a list of users in an array. But for some reason the following code always returns false. Some usernames do match and should therefore display a yes next to the username.

```
foreach($result AS $user){
    foreach($listarray AS $name){
        if($user['username'] == $name){
            $whitelisted = 'Yes';
        } else {
            $whitelisted = 'No';
        }
    }
    echo '<tr><td><p>'.$user['username'].'</p></td><td><p>'.$user['location'].'</p></td><td><p>'.$user['date_joined'].'</p></td><td><p>'.$whitelisted.'</p></td>';
}
```

Why is this comparison returning false even when some names should match?

Comment: Please post some sample data; hard to tell what's wrong without seeing your data structure.

Comment: Does `$user['username']` exist?  Do the cases match?  Is there extra whitespace in either `$user['username']` or `$name`?  You'll probably need to post some actual data to get a good answer here :)

Comment: Yes it does exist and no there is ño white space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `break` the inner `foreach` loop if there is a matching element. Alternatively you can use the `in_array` function to check if there is value exists in an array

```
foreach($result AS $user){
    $whitelisted = 'No';
    if (in_array($user['username'], $listarray ))
    {
       $whitelisted = 'Yes';
    }
    echo '<tr><td><p>'.$user['username'].'</p></td><td><p>'.$user['location'].'</p></td><td><p>'.$user['date_joined'].'</p></td><td><p>'.$whitelisted.'</p></td>';
}
```

Comment: More elegant thank you, I totally forgot the in_array function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to exit the loop with a break command when you find the match. Right now, your code is looping through each value in $result, then it takes that value and compares it to every value in $listarray. It's not comparing side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

the result of the comparison is assigned to a simple variable, overwriting it each time. that way if the last one is false it will always be false. moreover, the second foreach will execute all its iteration before getting back to the first one. this can be fixed with `continue;`:

```
foreach($result AS $user){
  foreach($listarray AS $name){
    if($user['username'] == $name){
        $whitelisted = 'Yes';
        continue; // that way when conpared as true, your other foreach can display result
    } else {
        $whitelisted = 'No';
    }
}
echo '<tr><td><p>'.$user['username'].'</p></td><td><p>'.$user['location'].'</p></td><td><p>'.$user['date_joined'].'</p></td><td><p>'.$whitelisted.'</p></td>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($result AS $user){
    $whitelisted = 'No';
    foreach($listarray AS $name){
        if($user['username'] == $name){
            $whitelisted = 'Yes';
        }
    }
    echo '<tr><td><p>'.$user['username'].'</p></td><td><p>'.$user['location'].'</p></td><td><p>'.$user['date_joined'].'</p></td><td><p>'.$whitelisted.'</p></td>';
}
```

Comment: You need to break the inner `foreach` if there is a matching element. Assume if first element is the match but last element is not a match then `$whitelisted` will always be `NO`

Comment: Khawer, that is wrong: "No" will only be seen, if there is no hit - it is assigned **before** the inner loop

Comment: Sorry my bad got it now, But still breaking the inner loop will save some time as if there is a match then there is no need to compare any further.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array('me', 'you', 'ours');
$b = array('me', 'mine', 'you');

$merge = array_merge($a, $b); // MERGER ARRAY
$dups = array_count_values($merge); // COUNT DUPLICATES

// STORE ALL DUPLICATED VALUES
$dup = array();
foreach($dups as $k => $v) {
    if($v > 1) {
        $dup[] = $k;
    }
}

echo '<pre> Duplicates: '; print_r($dup); echo '</pre>';
```

Result:

```
 Duplicates: Array
(
    [0] => me
    [1] => you
)
```

Check out my PHP Fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/t71-4db